# sculpt separated meshes

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I model CAD on Autodesk software, only used Blender when I was younger.

I split two meshes and I need to Sculpt them, only the original mesh is sculpt-able.

The mesh is from an .stl, and was separated by selection and hotkey  <kbd>P</kbd>.

Should, I change the material of each selection, then re-combine them? How do I edit the separated mesh?

I can sculpt the light grey, but not the dark grey. I separated or split the dark grey, specifically by using a selection and the hot key  <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: here is an explanation of how to sculpt 2 separate objects without having to go back into object mode, I can't test because of my settings but I guess it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXNZIIDZC48

Comment: thank you, however i'm not able to edit the other (split mesh). that video got my hopes up, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was t was similar to the posted video. By "changing the object in the current mode"

In scene selector, change the dot to the left of the mesh (to a sculpt icon) by going into sculpt mode, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Clicking</kbd> on it.